# Enable webRTC in cordova webview

Tags: android, cordova, webview, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have something like this in my cordova app

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
        window.location.href = 'https://mobile.xxx.com';                    
}
```

Now I need to use webRTC in this website. And works fine when I run it in mobile browser (chrome 54.0.2840.85).

However, when I use the apk, the webview will not load the webRTC features like camera or micro.

So, in mobile browser it works fine, in webview the rtc will not work.

This is what I have in config.xml

```
<content src="index.html" />

<access origin="https://mobile.xxx.com" /> 
<allow-navigation href="https://mobile.xxx.com" />
<allow-intent href="https://mobile.xxx.com" />

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information"       version="1.3.0"     source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen"              version="4.0.0"     source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist"                 version="1.3.0"     source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs"                   version="1.3.0"     source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar"                 version="2.2.0"     source="npm" />

<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView"   value="false" />
<preference name="phonegap-version"           value="cli-6.3.0" />
<preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>
<preference name="target-device"              value="universal"/>
<preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true"/>
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" /> 
<preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="true" />    
<preference name="orientation"            value="portrait" /> 
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue"        value="700000" />
```

Already tried [crosswalk](https://forums.adobe.com/message/9021337#9021337) but same problem. How can I have webrtc in cordova webview?
To clarify, I am just looking for a functional demo.

Comment: What version of Crosswalk were you using?

Comment: @johnborges already tried with ```<plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" />``` and with ```<plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview-pgb-adapt" source="npm" version="1.4.0-dev-5"/>```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what WebRTC specific features you're using but it isn't fully supported yet for most mobile browsers. See [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rtcpeerconnection).

Comment: As I said, camera / micro.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos , to access media we are supposed to make `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`

Similarly for mobile app, you will have to specify the permissions in config.xml related to camera or microphone that you are using.

For media access

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" spec="1.4.0">
    <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To take videos"/>
    <variable name="MICROPHONE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To record voice while taking videos"/>
    <variable name="PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To provide photo browsing."/>
</plugin>
```

For camera access

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="2.3.0">
    <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To take photos"/>
</plugin>
```

For more details of using the above plugins in mobile app, refer :
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture

Comment: Thanks, but even with this I am getting stream inactive.    ```stream.oninactive = function() {
    console.log('Stream inactive');
  };```

Comment: @user455318 did you figure this out?